# Convert "2013-02-04T10:30:23+00:00" to datetime using T-SQL (2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, type-conversion

Hi I am stuck in conversion of UTC DateTime strings "2013-02-04T10:30:23+00:00" to Sql 2005 datetime format.
I have tried 
**convert(datetime,'2013-02-04T10:30:23+00:00',101)** but it gives me error "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

However, this does work **convert(datetime,'2013-02-04 10:30:23',101)**.

Is there any work around for **convert(datetime,'2013-02-04T10:30:23+00:00',101)?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100) = '2013-02-04T10:30:23+00:00'
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@s, 10) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@s, 12, 8), 101)
```

This would extract the needed parts of the string, concatenate them into a new string and then use `CONVERT` to get the `DATETIME`.

Comment: Thank you! but i was looking for a solution without alteration of the strings as it will consume more resources while I have thousands of records to process.

Comment: Yes, that is true, if you were using SQL Server 2008 you could have `CAST(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, @s, 207) AS DATETIME)` but in SQL Server 2005 there is no `DATETIMEOFFSET` data type.

Comment: If there would be performance issues you could create a computed column of the above proposed definition, you would also have to create it with `PERSISTED` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @utc nvarchar(100) = '2013-02-04T10:30:23+00.00'
SELECT CAST(STUFF(@utc, CHARINDEX('+', @utc), LEN(@utc),'') AS datetime)
```